# Azure WebJob Deploy Error ManagementCertificatePath

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to deploy 2 WebJobs; 1 continuous and 1 scheduled. Part way through the deployment, the following errors happen:

Error   1   The "ManagementCertificatePath" parameter is not supported by the "CreateScheduledWebJob" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

Error   2   The "CreateScheduledWebJob" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Update:
I've updated all the NuGet packages and came across 2 Microsoft WebJobs Publish projects. Versions 1.0.0 and 1.0.1.

The 1.0.0 is on the Website project and the 1.0.1 is on the 2 WebJob projects. Neither report needing updates have different descriptions?!?

Comment: Fixed it. 2 part problem. Created a WebJob and then Deleted it before create 2 news ones but the old one was still in the webjobs-list.json file (Website Properties folder) and the second was the above 2 different packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - I'm not sure what helped, but I installed Update 4 for VS2013, installed the newest Azure Tools, deleted the existing Scheduler and WebJob and redeploy everything within VS and it wored.