# View Azure WebJob Schedule in Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I created a simple Azure WebJob with a schedule via the Visual Studio integration to run once per day.

I've deployed the WebJob and see it listed in my app on Azure.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "MyJob",
  "startTime": "2015-12-10T03:00:00-05:00",
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Day",
  "interval": 1,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

How can I actually once logged into the Azure Portal see that it will in fact run at 3 AM? I believe it uses the Scheduler under the hood, but I don't see it new entry in my list of Schedules.

Comment: Looks like more of my issue was the Scheduler JSON wasn't being deployed via GitHub... fixed now though! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158266/scheduled-azure-webjob-deployed-via-git-results-in-on-demand-job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest release, WebJobs can be trigger using the **TimerTrigger** so that you don't rely on the scheduler.

To answer your question, YES, the scheduled WebJob rely on the scheduler. If you don't see an item in the scheduler, I doubt it's going to run. So maybe you can configure it on the portal to ensure it's going to run.

My suggestion is to completely migrate to the new WebJobs SDK and use the TimerTrigger Extension.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

In the new portal, click Browse / Scheduler Collections. You should see a collection containing the job that hits your WebApp.

As an aside, the preferred approach is now to scheduler your WebJob using a CRON expressing, instead of relying on the scheduler. See details on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON.